# Why Unique Opens and Total Open Rates Showing Zero in Report?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using three emails in a journey builder and when I am creating a report the get the open rate of the emails,
It is showing me the Zero open rate?
Why it is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possible reasons:

1. You forgot to include the below open tracking snippet in your email: `<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking" />`
2. You don't have any opens for those emails.

Comment: Thank you very much!